# How can I disable Word's built-in Ribbon Tabs when a specific document is loaded?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am using the following code right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<commands>
<command idMso="Font" enabled="false"/>
<command idMso="AlignLeft" enabled="false"/>
<command idMso="AlignCenter" enabled="false"/>
<command idMso="AlignRight" enabled="false"/>
</commands>
```

and so on, but this completely disables the buttons obviously. I now want to restrict my users from being able to use certain built-in Word controls when a *specific* document is loaded, and leave them with the liberty of doing whatever the rest of the time.  I have tried to use:

```
<command idMso="FontSize" getEnabled="checkDisable"/>
```

where `checkDisable` checks for what documents are open.  That document is then searched for a string (that's how I know I want to disable the buttons), but the checkDisable callback fires before the document is actually loaded.
Can I somehow directly disable specific buttons from the codebehind instead of just via XML?  If I could do this, I could disable the buttons on the DocumentLoaded event.

ANY suggestions are appreciated, I've been banging my head against the wall Googling this one for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right avenue. You need to use callbacks instead of attributes. But Office caches the values and don't call the callbacks each time as you want it. Instead, to refresh the UI (force Office application to invoke callbacks) you need to use the [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate(v=office.14).aspx) or [InvalidateControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol(v=office.14).aspx) methods of the IRibbonUI interface. See [Overview of the IRibbonUI Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869817.aspx) for more information.

For example, when you open a new document in the host application the [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821870.aspx) event is fired. You can check out the Document and call the Invalidate method (if required) to force the host application to call your callbacks and therefore refresh the UI.

Comment: On which object is Invalidate called or how to use these callbacks? Where does the IRibbonUI come from?