# Hide MS Word "Table Tools" in the ribbon when editing a table

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbonx

I have a word document with custom ribbon where *TabTableToolsDesign* and *TabTableToolsLayout*  are hidden (visible is set to false).
My problem is that i have a table in my document and when the cursor is in one of the cells of this table, the ribbons displays "Table Tools". How may i avoid this ?

Comment: You need to trap application events, such as DocumentChange, and use callbacks to invalidate the ribbon. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882410/how-can-i-disable-words-built-in-ribbon-tabs-when-a-specific-document-is-loaded

Answer (score -1):

Right click in the ribbon then click "Customize Ribbon". On the right side, click the drop down and select "Tool Tabs", then uncheck "Table Tools" [image: like so].

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works but it's applied to every word document. How apply this to one particular document?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, ribbon customizations are saved for your specific Word account and are applied across all Word instances where you are the user.

Comment: That's only true for the end-user, but not for a programmed solution.

Comment: @CindyMeister as far as I'm aware, Word 2013 and on have removed ribbon customization, no? At least without add-ins, which is not a VBA solution.

Comment: No, Ribbon XML + VBA works just the same. Also in later versions of Office software.